# How to filter the data in model class and display accurately according to letters not words in table view?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

Here I need to place a local search for my model class data that displayed in the table view and I tried to implement the search for that I placed successfully but the search was should be like when I enter the first letter it should filter depending on the first letter, not with th letter in all objects

for example in brand names I am having **Fastrack, Microsoft, Dell, apple, fila**

if I type `f` then it should display only **fastrack** and **fila** but it displays **fastrack**,**fila** and **Microsoft** which containing **f**

but I need like when the first letter should be equal to `f` then it should display fastback and file only not Microsoft and if the second letter equals with any another word then it should display filtered results

Here is my code

```
 var bannerModel = [BrandBanners]()
 var searchActive : Bool?
 var filteredData = [BrandBanners]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if searchActive == true {
            return filteredData.count
        }
        else {
            return bannerModel.count
        }
    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)  as! superBrandTableViewCell
        if searchActive == true {
            cell.brandImageView.kf.indicatorType = .activity
            let item = filteredData[indexPath.row]
            if URL(string: (item.brandImageforMobile)!) != nil {
                let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: URL(string: (item.brandImageforMobile)!)!, cacheKey: item.brandImageforMobile)
                cell.brandImageView.kf.setImage(with: resource, placeholder: nil, options: nil, progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: nil)
            }
            else {
                cell.brandImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "placeholder")
            }
            cell.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        }
        else {
            cell.brandImageView.kf.indicatorType = .activity
            let item = bannerModel[indexPath.row]
            if URL(string: (item.brandImageforMobile)!) != nil {
                let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: URL(string: (item.brandImageforMobile)!)!, cacheKey: item.brandImageforMobile)
                cell.brandImageView.kf.setImage(with: resource, placeholder: nil, options: nil, progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: nil)
            }
            else {
                cell.brandImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "placeholder")
            }
            cell.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        }
        return cell
    }
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
            self.filteredData = self.bannerModel
        } else {
            var lowerCase = searchBar.text!
            self.filteredData = bannerModel.filter({($0.brand?.lowercased().contains(lowerCase.lowercased()))!})
        }
        self.searchActive = true
        brandTableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: What you are looking for is `hasPrefix` instead of `contains`

Comment: yes according to prefix @PrashantTukadiya

Comment: Check the answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `hasPrefix` Method to achieve this

Example

```
struct User {
    var userName : String = ""
    var password : String = ""
}



var array = [User.init(userName:"Test",password:"123456"),User.init(userName:"TEMP",password:"123456"),User.init(userName:"Prashant",password:"123456"),User.init(userName:"Test",password:"123456")]

array = array.filter{$0.userName.hasPrefix("T")} // Observe hasPrefix instead of contains  
print(array)
```

For your code

```
self.filteredData = bannerModel.filter({($0.brand?.lowercased().hasPrefix(lowerCase.lowercased()))!})
```

**EDIT For Type Safety**

```
    self.filteredData = bannerModel.filter({($0.brand ?? "").lowercased().hasPrefix("H".lowercased())}
```

Hope it is helpful

Comment: @User Thanks for accepting answer one more thing to point out is should not forcefully unwrap `!` put a check would be a safe :)

Comment: thanks @Prashant Tukadiya I already used a check i.e this condition for that is `if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
            self.filteredData = self.bannerModel
        } else {
            var lowerCase = searchBar.text!
            self.filteredData = bannerModel.filter({($0.brand?.lowercased().contains(lowerCase.lowercased()))!})
        }` if searcher text nil then it won't allow is it sufficient ?

Comment: @User There is no problem with search text at all !! Check updated asnwer

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
self.filteredData = bannerModel.filter({($0.brand?.lowercased().hasPrefix(lowerCase.lowercased()))!})
```